# Splitting a special type of list data and saving data into two separate dataframe using condition in python

Tags: python, text-files

Want to seperate a list data into two parts based on condition. If the value is less than "H1000", we want in a first dataframe(Output for list 1) and if it is greater or equal to "H1000" we want in a second dataframe(Output for list2). First column starts the value with H followed by a four numbers.

Here is my python code:

```
with open(fn) as f:
  text = f.read().strip()
   print(text)
   lines = [[(Path(fn.name), line_no + 1, col_no + 1, cell) for col_no, cell in enumerate(
                re.split('\t', l.strip())) if cell != ''] for line_no, l in enumerate(re.split(r'[\r\n]+', text))]
    print(lines)
    if (lines[:][:][3] == "H1000"):
        list1
        list2
```

I am not able to write a python logic to divide the list data into two parts.

Attach python code & file [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tbsR6zMdWuE67VzaiVje-VZXawI0waDL?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you please explain in detail what it means 'If the value is less than "H1000" '?

Comment: Want to make two list based on first column value(See Input text file).

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to check if the number after the H is greater or not than 1000 right? If I'm right then just do like this:

```
with open(fn) as f:
  text = f.read().strip()
   print(text)
   lines = [[(Path(fn.name), line_no + 1, col_no + 1, cell) for col_no, cell in enumerate(
                re.split('\t', l.strip())) if cell != ''] for line_no, l in enumerate(re.split(r'[\r\n]+', text))]
    print(lines)
    value = lines[:][:][3]
    if value[1:].isdigit():
        if (int(value[1:]) < 1000):
            #list 1
        else:
            #list 2
```

we simply take the numerical part of the factor "hxxxx" with the slices, convert it into an integer and compare it with 1000

Comment: it is not working. I want both the list. list 1 contain list of less than "H1000", we want in a first dataframe(See this-Output for list 1)  and list 2 contain list greater than "H1000"(See this-Output for list 2).  Please see how the output look like. Can you please test it as I have attached  test file and python code.

Comment: It is throwing error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit''

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(fn) as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
lines =text.split('\n')
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in lines:
    if int(i.split(' ')[0].replace("H",""))>=1000:
        list2.append(i)
    else:
        list1.append(i)
print(list1)
print("***************************************")
print(list2)
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0002\tVersion\t3\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'. This error coming. For testing you can download the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where the problem lies. Assuming you read the above text file line by line, you can simply make use of `str.__le__` to check your condition, e.g.

```
lines = """
H0002   Version 3
H0003   Date_generated  5-Aug-81
H0004   Reporting_period_end_date   09-Jun-99
H0005   State   WAA
H0999   Tene_no/Combined_rept_no    E79/38975
H1001   Tene_holder Magnetic Resources NL   
""".strip().split("\n")
# Or
# with open(fn) as f: lines = f.readlines()

list_1, list_2 = [], []
for line in lines:
    if line[:6] <= "H1000":
        list_1.append(line)
    else:
        list_2.append(line)


print(list_1, list_2, sep="\n")
# ['H0002   Version 3', 'H0003   Date_generated  5-Aug-81', 'H0004   Reporting_period_end_date   09-Jun-99', 'H0005   State   WAA', 'H0999   Tene_no/Combined_rept_no    E79/38975']
# ['H1001   Tene_holder Magnetic Resources NL']
```

Comment: if line[:6] <= "H1000":  column number is 6 is not fixed. It is dynamic. I have put only one file for testing but there are bunch of text files where position of H1000 is different. Files attached in the question. I want column number 6 dynamic in my code. any idea???